# Creating shortcuts in activity for other activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to make an application in which when i click the button a menu opens displaying all the activities on the phone and when i choose one of the activity its shortcut is made on the activity using list view. I have started to write some code but i am not getting the path of activity returned so any help is appreciated.

I want to create shortcut of the activity chosen from the list. So i don't know how ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.sheraz.voice;

import java.util.List;    
import android.app.Activity;    
import android.content.Intent;    
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;    
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;    
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Voice extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY, null);
        //mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        final List pkgAppsList = this.getPackageManager()
                .queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
        Log.e("App", pkgAppsList.toString());
        startActivityForResult(mainIntent, RESULT_OK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    }
}
```